# map from $D$ to $\pi(D)$ is injective?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

please follow this [map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}/L$ is open map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174456/map-from-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-l-is-open-map) ,let w be a non zero element of the lattice L so that |w|>2ϵ, fix such ϵ>0 and any $z_0$∈C and take an open disk of radius ϵ with centre at $z_0$, could you please tell me why $π:D\rightarrow π(D)$ is injective? what does it mean by a "lattice" of small disk in $\mathbb{C}$? what is π(D) pictorically? let my $L=\{m_1(1,0)+m_2(0,1):m_1,m_2\in\mathbb{Z}$}

Comment: You know, considering your username is **Patience**, you might have taken more than a couple of hours to digest the answers you received to your previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you gave cannot be correct because there are points with arbitrarily high magnitude in $L$, so that would imply that $\pi$ is injective over $\mathbb C$.

You need $|w|>2\varepsilon$ for *every* non-zero $w\in L$, not just a single one.

Once you make that correction, $\pi(x)=\pi(y) \iff y-x\in L$, but since $|y-x|\le 2\varepsilon$ this can only be true if $x=y$.

Answer (score 2):

So interestingly enough, the answer is similar to the other one I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174447/why-this-map-is-injective/174448#174448) in concept. The important thing is understanding equivalence classes!

You have a map from a set to a set which is a quotient map. Elements of $\mathbb{C}/L$ are equivalence classes of $\mathbb{C}$ mod an equivalence relation. Hence two points in $\mathbb{C}$ will map to the same *class* if they are representatives of the same class.  You need to show that that can't happen.

You should work out the following

- what is the equivalence relation in question?
- when are two points in $\mathbb{C}$ representatives of the same class?
- why cant two points in the neighborhood you describe be representatives of the same class, based on the first two things?
- this shows the map is injective. Why?

Comment: *this only works once you fix the typo @generic mentions.